# Deleting part of string in subfolder name then in files within

Tags: excel, vba

I have a ton of files that have a common string in the name "mch". Within one folder there are hundreds of subfolders named with this common string, then within those there are 5 pictures named similar; example picfront1234mch. I need to get rid of the mch at the end of all the names of picture files and the folders they are in. I was attempting a couple different examples from the web but non to work. I wrote this code to find the file names in the subfolders and to delete the last 3 characters of the name but its deleting the extensions instead. I have used the move/copy/ rename method in the past but I lost some of my old code and can’t figure out how use it again. Any suggestions on how to do this better?

Code ive been trying

```
Option Explicit

Sub ListFiles()



'Declare the variables

Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject

Dim objTopFolder As Scripting.Folder

Dim strTopFolderName As String



'Assign the top folder to a variable

strTopFolderName = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Test"



'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")



'Get the top folder

Set objTopFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strTopFolderName)



'Call the RecursiveFolder routine

Call RecursiveFolder(objTopFolder, True)



End Sub



Sub RecursiveFolder(objFolder As Scripting.Folder, IncludeSubFolders As Boolean)

'Declare the variables

Dim objFile As Scripting.File

Dim objSubFolder As Scripting.Folder

Dim str As String



Debug.Print Now

Application.SendKeys "^g ^a {DEL}"



Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Loop through each folder in the Topfolder

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

    str = objFile.Name

    Debug.Print str

    'delete last 3 chara of string

    str = Left(str, Len(str) - 3)

    Debug.Print str

Next objFile

If IncludeSubFolders Then

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders

        Call RecursiveFolder(objSubFolder, True)

    Next objSubFolder

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Usage:**
`RemoveTextFromFileName "mch", "I:\stackoverflow\temp"`

```
   Sub RemoveTextFromFileName(txt As String, FolderName As String)
        Dim file
        If Not Right(FolderName, 1) = "\" Then FolderName = FolderName & "\"

        file = Dir(FolderName)
        While (file  "")
            If InStr(file, txt) > 0 Then

                FileCopy FolderName & file, FolderName & Replace(file, txt, "")

                Kill FolderName & file

            End If
            file = Dir
        Wend

    End Sub
```

[image]

**Update:** Remove string from folder, sub folders, and file names.

These functions will recursively search the root folder and all it's subfolders to rename files and folders.

**Usage:**

Public Sub ProcessFoldersAndFiles()

```
ReplaceStringFileNames "C:\Data Files\mch files\", "mch"

ReplaceStringDirectories"C:\Data Files\mch files\", "mch"
```

End Sub

Here are the functions:

```
Sub ReplaceStringDirectories(FolderPath As String, SearchString As String, Optional ReplacementString As String = "", Optional fso As Object)
    Dim fld, thisFolder

    Dim NewName As String, PathOnly As String

    If fso Is Nothing Then

        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    End If

    Set thisFolder = fso.getFolder(FolderPath)

    For Each fld In thisFolder.Subfolders
        ReplaceStringDirectories fld.Path, SearchString, ReplacementString
    Next


    If InStr(thisFolder.Name, SearchString) Then

        NewName = Replace(thisFolder.Name, SearchString, ReplacementString, , , vbTextCompare)

        PathOnly = Left(thisFolder.Path, InStrRev(thisFolder.Path, "\"))

        Do Until Not fso.FolderExists(PathOnly & NewName)
            NewName = "_" & NewName
        Loop

        thisFolder.Name = NewName

    End If

End Sub

Sub ReplaceStringFileNames(FolderPath As String, SearchString As String, Optional ReplacementString As String = "", Optional fso As Object)
    Dim f, fld, thisFolder

    Dim NewName As String, PathOnly As String

    If fso Is Nothing Then

        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    End If


    Set thisFolder = fso.getFolder(FolderPath)

    For Each fld In thisFolder.Subfolders
        ReplaceStringFileNames fld.Path, SearchString, ReplacementString
    Next

    For Each f In thisFolder.Files

        If InStr(f.Name, SearchString) Then

            NewName = Replace(f.Name, SearchString, ReplacementString, , , vbTextCompare)

            PathOnly = Left(f.Path, InStrRev(thisFolder.Path, "\"))

            Do Until Not fso.FolderExists(PathOnly & NewName)
                NewName = "_" & NewName
            Loop

            f.Name = NewName

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, does this work for folders too?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, lol.  I added two functions that will recursively search your directories and rename files and folders.  I recommend backing up the files.  If a file would be renamed to an existing file name then "_" will be added to the beginning of it's name.

Comment: do I actually put in the `ReplaceStringFileNames "C:\Data Files\mch files\", "test"` and 

`ReplaceStringDirectories"C:\Data Files\mch files\", "test"` ?

Comment: Yes, use you own folder path and "mch" instead of "test".

Comment: ok I have it above all the code and changed it to my file path but it doesn't give me an option to run it, you know when you click run it ask which macro to run. its just blank? I must be missing something?

Comment: .. nvm I had to put the functions in a sub.. duh.. Thanks for your help! works perfectly

Comment: I just wrapped the code in a sub.  You can run it in a sub or from the immediate window.

Comment: Glad that I could help.